# which means I can transfer a fie into gem5 run virtual system,say ubuntu,

Tags: gem5

as the title mentioned,I run gem5 fs mode,I just want send a file into the ubuntu system,when virtual system is running, I've tried m5 command like: m5 readfile > /tmp/file.txt,it doesn't work, not like m5 writefile has parameter hostname,can someone help me,thanks

expectiong succ send a file into gem5 running vm